# How can i reuse UIView Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

i want to achieve like this image .

[image]

here is my **view**  i want to reuse it for separator line

```
var sparteLine : UIView = {
        var view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue // color blue for testing 
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
```

i just try to do it by this way but it is not working .. it only showing last separator line . first one not showing . what can i do ?:

```
    addSubview(sparteLine)
    addSubview(disComment)
    addSubview(disCommentTextField)
    addSubview(sparteLine)
```

full source code here : https://gist.github.com/nazmulkp/c0b57185f76fb426634c65eb0476889e

thank you . if your need any information then let me know please :

Comment: as you are using `sparteLine` is global view variable so its overridding object value with last initiated object and thats why its taking last object and set only last object frame.

Comment: Can you show your `disComment` view code ? how you are adding that view ?

Comment: I have already check that gist but there is no declaration of that view only seperatorView is there.

Comment: @CodeChanger update that one please check please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're attempting to add the same view as a subview more than once, which is not possible.

What you could do, is create a function that creates your separator view, and create one each time you need one.

```
func createSeparatorLine() -> UIView {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .blue
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}
```

Each time you need to use it, simply call this function

```
let separator1 = createSeparatorLine()
addSubview(separator1)
```

**EDIT** Good point Grimxn

```
var separator: UIView {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .blue
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}

addSubview(separator)
```

Comment: No need for a function - he *could* use a `var` as long as it's a getter, rather than an execute once closure (as he currently has it).

Comment: @Grimxn could you give your answer

Comment: @DanW, Nazmul - Dan's point is correct, but I suspect that so are the other commentators who point out that the frames and/or constraints need set properly too...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change code little bit.

as per my observation while you are setting `Constrains` its taking new object so catch that view object in local variable and use it for setting `Constrains`.

Like this :

```
 let aSparteLine = sparteLine
 self.view.addSubview(aSparteLine)


//Mark :- sparteLine

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: aSparteLine, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10).isActive = true

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: aSparteLine, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: 10).isActive = true

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: aSparteLine, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, multiplier: 1, constant: -10).isActive = true

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: aSparteLine, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .height, multiplier:0, constant: 5).isActive = true
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: let aSparteLine = sparteLine
 self.addSubview(aSparteLine) . it is tableview cell

Comment: Yes so for that you need to post full code otherwise we can not guide you by partially code gist.

Answer (score 0):

There are *two* problems with you code:

1) your definition of `sparteLine` is an *execute-once* closure, and so you are trying to add the *same instance* of `UIView` as a subview twice, which as @DanW points out, will not work. There are two ways to fix that:

**either** make the `var` a getter rather than an execute-once closure:

```
var separator: UIView {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .blue
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}
```

**or** make it a function. In either case, you will then have two separate instances of UIView.

2) You are not setting the frames and/or constraints of the `UIView`s, so they will default to no size, and overlapping.

Try this in Playground (other views removed for clarity):

```
func sparteLine(_ y: CGFloat, _ colour: UIColor) -> UIView {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: 200, height: 100))
    view.backgroundColor = colour // color blue for testing
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}

let mainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
mainView.addSubview(sparteLine(0, .blue))
mainView.addSubview(sparteLine(100, .red))
mainView
```

[image]